# Existence of a suitable binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible to define an **associative binary operation** $*$   on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that  $x*x*y=y*x*x=y$   for   $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @Peter Um, what? $2\times 2\times 3\not=3$ . . .

Comment: I overlooked the "=y" at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitwise xor has this property.  It's commutative, too, and extends to the reals.

Comment: @ Mnemonic , can you please prove this rigorously . I need a formal proof that bitwise  xor indeed works . :)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness), and this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961441/xor-is-commutative-associative-and-its-own-inverse-are-there-any-other-such-f).

Comment: It's defined bitwise, so you can consider each bit separately.  Then there are only four cases to check.